# Erlang, reading a file with character offset

Tags: erlang

I have code to find a specific occurance of text in a file and give me an offset so I know where this occurance end. Now I want to read the file from that offset to the end of the file. The file contains binary data as well as text. How do I do this in Erlang?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `pread`. (See [Erlang documentation on the file module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html)). You have to take care of any character encoding yourself as the function deals with only bytes.